# Could you please help with vectors? Specific questions below

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Could someone please help me answer these questions. Haven't done maths in 6 years! :O

(a). Find a vector equation for the line through the points $A(1,1,1)$ and $B (2,1,1)$.

(b). Find a general equation for a plane through the points of the triangle which has vertices at $C(1,1,-1), D(2,-1,1)$ and $E(-1,3,3)$.

(c). Find the point $F$, where the line from (a) intersects the plane from (b).

(d). Determine whether the point $F$ is inside the triangle $CDE$.

Answer (score 1):

(a) $A(1,1,1)$ and $B(2,1,1)$, subtract $B$ from $A$ to get the vector $\vec{AB} = [1,0,0]$. From here, we can parameterize the vector using the point $A$ to generate the equation for the line passing thru $A$ and $B$:
$\boxed{x = 1+t, y=1,z=1}$

(b) Find two vectors originating from the same point, we will use $C$. $\vec{CD} = [1,-2,2]$ and $\vec{CE} = [-2,2,4]$. Now we will take the cross product of these two vectors to produce a new vector orthogonal to them. $\vec{CD} \times \vec{CE} = [ \begin{vmatrix}-2 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{vmatrix}, -\begin{vmatrix}1 & 2 \\ -2 & 4 \end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}1 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{vmatrix}] = [-12,-8,-2]$. We will then use point $C$ and this vector to form the equation. The general form of a plan equation is $a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are the components of the orthogonal vector to the plan and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point on the plan. Putting this all together we get: $\boxed{-12(x-1)-8(y-1)-2(z+1)=0}$

(c) Plug in $x,y$ and $z$ from the parameterize equation we found in (a) to the equation in (c) and solve for $t$: $$-12((1+t)-1)-8(1-1)-2(1+1)=0\\
-12t-4=0\\
-12t=4$$
So, $t=-\frac{1}{3}$. Plug this into the equation from (a) again to get: $x=1+-\frac{1}{3},y=1,z=1$. Thus the point of intersection $\boxed{F = (\frac{2}{3},1,1)}$

(d) We will use [barycentric coordinates](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/); we found previously $\vec{CD} = [1,-2,2]$ and $\vec{CE} = [-2,2,4]$. Now we find $\vec{CF} = [-\frac{1}{3},0,2]$. Then we calculate the following: 
$$\vec{CD} \cdot \vec{CD} = ||\vec{CD}||^2 = 9\\
\vec{CD} \cdot \vec{CE} = 2\\
\vec{CD} \cdot \vec{CF} = \frac{11}{3}\\
\vec{CE} \cdot \vec{CE} = ||\vec{CE}||^2 = 24\\
\vec{CE} \cdot \vec{CF} = \frac{26}{3}$$
$u = \frac{(24\cdot\frac{11}{3})-(2\cdot\frac{26}{3})}{(9\cdot24)-(2\cdot2)} = \frac{1}{3}$ and $v = \frac{(9\cdot\frac{26}{3})-(2\cdot\frac{11}{3})}{(9\cdot24)-(2\cdot2)} = \frac{1}{3}$. $u \geq 0$, $v \geq 0$, and $u+v = \frac{1}{9} < 1$, thus $\boxed{F \text{ lies in the triangle } CDE}$

Comment: On (d), three points _determine_ a plane, so $ \ C \ , \ D \ , $ and $ \ E \ $ are certainly co-planar.  The point $ \ F \ $ _also_ lies in that plane, since it is an intersection point with the line of (a) , so we want to know whether it is found in the interior of the triangle $ \ CDE \ $ . (I think you're thinking of the _vectors_ forming the sides of a pyramid, but that's not what is involved here.)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I updated my answer to reflect this. I completely over-thought that. Thanks.

Comment: It's all right -- the wording and intent of a problem isn't necessarily clear to everyone; I've had my share of problem statements that seemed like nonsense to me...